# PHP Foreach loop - missing data - how to create in with a "no data" response rather than receiving a warning

Tags: php, foreach

Thank you for any assistance that you may offer with this...

I'm creating a page with a bunch of weather reports from various weather instruments.  The issue that I'm having is that sometimes these instruments do not send the certain pieces of data, for various reasons.  I'm using a foreach loop to display all of the weather conditions...but if a station didn't submit, for example a wind gust value, then I get a warning within the list.  Obviously, I would rather have the list just say "no data" or something...rather than the big red warning box.

Here is the code that I've been working on...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th>Temperature°F</th>
            <th>Dew Point°F</th>
            <th>Humidity%</th>
            <th>Wind Direction</th>
            <th>Wind Speed MPH</th>
            <th>Wind Gust MPH</th>
            <th>Pressure (mb)</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($data->STATION as $site): ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo($site->NAME); ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->air_temp_value_1)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->dew_point_temperature_value_1d)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->relative_humidity_value_1)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_cardinal_direction_value_1d)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_speed_value_1)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_gust_value_1)->value; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo($site->OBSERVATIONS->sea_level_pressure_value_1d)->value; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

These all come from JSON data from an API.  The issue is that if a new observation from weather instrument does not send a wind gust value...then there is nothing in the JSON data for that variable.  But, my code is still searching for it in the JSON data.  Therefore, I get the warning:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$wind_gust_value_1 in C:\wamp64\www\mesowesttable.php on line 48

Is there some way to have the table populated with "No data" rather than getting the warning?  Some type of "if/then" statement?

Thank you all,

Justin

Comment: Check if `stdClass::$wind_gust_value_1` is set _before_ line 48, and it it's not, populate "no data".

Comment: Go _research_ that warning message, and you will find lots of results showing you how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if is value set for that variable:

```
$wind_gust_value = isset($site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_gust_value_1->value) ? $site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_gust_value_1->value : 'empty';
echo $wind_gust_value;
```

or first initialize with some data

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHPs [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (??) to check if the value is set or not.

```
<?php echo $site->OBSERVATIONS->wind_gust_value_1->value ?? 'no data'; ?>
```